# Get list of latest installed python packages

Tags: python, pip, package

I am trying to get an ordered list of the lastest installed packages in Python. I am using pip (I cannot use -conda or terminal). The instruction `pip list` returns all the packages I have ever installed. Since I installed a package which damaged the older ones, I need the list of the latest installed packages in order to uninstall only them and reinstall them later. In simple words, I need to do a rollback. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the packages, with:

```
import pkg_resources
import os
import time

for package in pkg_resources.working_set:
    print(f'{package}\n, Installed: {time.ctime(os.path.getctime(package.location))}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Would `pip freeze` help you ?
It writes a list like that :

```
# pip freeze

attrs==21.2.0
branca==0.4.2
cached-property==1.5.2
certifi==2021.10.8
charset-normalizer==2.0.8
...
```